# Corkboard software

Tags: mind-mapping

I am a writing a book. I am looking for a plain corkboard software, something like [Pinup](https://pinup.com/); or Scrivener's corkboard feature (image below). While Pinup is okay, moving around is a bit of a hassle. (For example, if I am at the bottom of a big board, when I create new pin I need to go up and grab it and take to the bottom, etc.) It can be an online service or a desktop application (I am on Linux.) I rather fancy something plain, but one feature I would love to see is be able to make connections between the pins.

I don't mind those trendy mind-mapping software, but most of them are bloated.

[image]